# Converting hexadecimal string to dynamic primitive type

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code:

```
        string hexString = "0x00000004";
        Type hexType = typeof(Int32);

        object o = Convert.ChangeType(hexString, hexType);
```

Which throws a **System.FormatException** as soon as it is executed as, apparantly, Convert.ChangeType can't work with hexadecimal values.

My other alternatives are using either of these:

- **Int32**.Parse
- Convert.**ToInt32**

However, since they apply for a specific type, I'll need to use a **switch**/reflection to choose the correct function for the correct type.

I am not really excited about either of these options. Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since hexadecimal is usually used only for integer numbers, you can [parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkw23d3e.aspx) the string to the largest integer type (Int64) and [change](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx) the type of the result to the desired type:

```
string hexString = "deadcafebabe0000";
long hexValue = long.Parse(hexString, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);

Type hexType = typeof(Int32);
object o = Convert.ChangeType(hexValue, hexType);
```

(Note that you need to strip out the `0x` prefix before passing the string to the Parse method.)

---

[Convert.ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx) is essentially a big pile of `if (type == ...) ... else if (type == ...)` statements. You could create a dictionary that maps all integer types to their respective [Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkw23d3e.aspx) method:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>>
{
    { typeof(byte),   s => byte.Parse(s, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier) },
    { typeof(sbyte),  s => sbyte.Parse(s, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier) },
    { typeof(short),  s => short.Parse(s, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier) },
    { typeof(ushort), s => ushort.Parse(s, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier) },
    { typeof(int),    s => int.Parse(s, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier) },
    { typeof(uint),   s => uint.Parse(s, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier) },
    { typeof(long),   s => long.Parse(s, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier) },
    { typeof(ulong),  s => ulong.Parse(s, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier) },
};

string hexString = (-5).ToString("X");
Type hexType = typeof(Int32);
object o = dict[hexType](hexString);
```

Comment: @VitalyB: Negative hexadecimal numbers are an ugly corner case, because they're not represented with a `-` sign (base 16) but in its Two's complement. This means you need to parse the string using exactly the same type as the original value.

Comment: I was hoping for something more built-in. Oh well, I guess I'll go with this. Thanks!